# Priority queue and deque

Tags: algorithm, priority-queue, deque

I was doing this question http://www.spoj.com/problems/SHOP/ .The question boils down to calculating shortest path between 2 points in a weighted graph where verticecs have weights.i implemented a working solution using bfs https://code.hackerearth.com/ff00c2Z, it works fine on sample test cases but gives WA verdict ,when i googled some solutions 
i saw that the actual solution uses dijkstra .when i tried to find my mistake i saw that i had used deque instead of priority queue what difference does it makes in this case ?why deque is not working ? is my approach wrong ? then how can this problem be done using BFS?

Comment: Hi animefn. It is better to include the important information from the links into your question itself as the link may later on go bad.

Comment: One thing to note is that as edges do not have weight,rather the vertices have weight,hence we can we use modified BFS instead of Dijkstra algorithm, because the edges have a weight of one.

Comment: I did the same thing but seems like i did a mistake which i am not able to find

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `deque` instead of `priority queue` and you are asking what is wrong?
First of all in `dequeue` you have not prioritized things here based on distance. The first enqueued object or last enqueued object is always given the highest preference but it might be the case that a middle element should have highest priority (it might become a highest priority object) That's why you are getting WA.

---

**Note:** I have just stated the pre-condition for using dijkstra. You can also solve this problem using `BFS` and also using `Dijkstra`.

**Note 2:** Use data structure when needed. You don't need deque in BFS just use a queue and that will suffice otherwise it becomes more complex to handle for large code.

1. [BFS Using Queue in C++ STL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416851/implementing-graph-and-bfs-in-c-using-stl)

Comment: how we can know the priority of the elements being stored ?

Comment: in case of dijkstra you alwaya priritize the ones with shortest distance from source. That's the prioritizing property in Dijkstra.

Comment: I see but how come BFS gives wrong ans although shortest path can be calculated using deque in BFS

Comment: Using queue in BFS ( why are you gonna use deque when queue is suffiecient?).If the given graph is weighted, BFS does not work. This is because there can be ‘longer’ path(s)
(in terms of number of vertices/edges involved in the path) but has smaller total weight than the‘shorter’ path found by BFS.

Comment: i get it i am wrong ,so does that mean this question cannot be solved using modified bfs

Comment: @animefn.: hey it is possible using bfs also,,,,use a queue or deuque but just one end of the queue front only..

Comment: can you edit my code or perhaps  show me a similar  example ,where queue is used.

Comment: @animefn.:check my answer and follow the link